# Trouble wiring back button with django

Tags: python, django, django-views

Quite new with django and so having difficulties with trying to wire my pages together.

I have an Applicant page that has a button to go to a Create Application page. I'm passing it like this:

```
<a class="btn btn-default btn-sm" href="{% url 'applicant:application-new' applicant.pk %}">
    <i class="fa fa-file"></i> Create Application
</a>
```

From the Create Application page, how do I wire it back to the Applicant page?

I've tried doing it this way but I get this error "**Reverse for 'applicant-update' with arguments '('',)' not found.** "

```
 <a class="btn btn-default btn-sm" href="{% url 'applicant:application-new' applicant.pk %}">
     <i class="fa fa-fw fa-arrow-circle-left"></i> Back
 </a>
```

My urls:

```
app_name = 'applicant'
urlpatterns = [    
    url(r'view/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', views.ApplicantUpdate.as_view(), name='applicant-update'),
    url(r'view/(?P<pk>\d+)/new/$', views.ApplicationCreate.as_view(), name='application-new'),
]
```

View for Create Application:

```
@method_decorator(login_required, name='dispatch')
class ApplicationCreate(SuccessMessageMixin, CreateView):
    form_class = ApplicationForm
    template_name = 'applicant_application.html'
    success_message = 'Successfully created application.'
```

I hope you can help me. Thank you very much.

Comment: The URLs don't make much sense as they are. You're passing a pk to ApplicationCreate, but you're not doing anything at all with it in the view.

Answer (score 0):

I imagine the issue is what Daniel commented. Your URL to create a new object is expecting a PK, which doesn't exist so the Django URL dispatcher cannot find a match.

You probably want something like this for your URLs:

```
app_name = 'applicant'
urlpatterns = [    
    url(r'view/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', views.ApplicantUpdate.as_view(), name='applicant-update'),
    url(r'view/new/$', views.ApplicationCreate.as_view(), name='application-new'),
]
```

And something like this for your reverse URL:

```
{% url 'applicant:application-new' %}
```